# Prepping Data For Usage Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science, data-cleaning, bigdata

Dataset: I'm given the number of minutes individual customers use a product each day and am trying to cluster this data in order to find common usage patterns.

My question: How can I format the data so that, for example, a power user with high levels of use for a year looks the same as a different power user who has only been able to use the device for a month before I ended data collection?

So far I've turned each customer into an array where each cell is the number of minutes used that day. This array starts when the user first uses the product and ends after the user's first year of use. All entries in the cells must be double values (e.x. 200.0 minutes used) for the clustering model. I've considered either setting all cells/days after the last day of data collection to either -1.0 or NULL. Are either of these a valid approach? If not what would you suggest?

Comment: Please **don't cross-post**: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/11456/924

Comment: The Data Science Community is much smaller, I didn't anticipate a response in any timely manner even if they were more qualified in this subject. Why is it inappropriate to post the same question to two separate communities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem where you want both users (one that used the product a lot every day for a year, and the other used it a lot for one month), create a new entry where it's values are:

```
avg_usage per time_bin
```

time_bin can be a month, a day or another time bin which best fits your needs.
This way, a user which use a product, let's say 200 minutes per day for one year, will get:

```
200 * 30 * 12 / 12 = 6000 minutes per month
```

and the other user, which joined just last month, will also get, with the exact same usage will get:

```
200 * 30 * 1 / 1 = 6000 minutes per month.
```

This way, it doesn't matter when you have started to use the product, the only thing that matter, is the usage rate.

An important thing you might take into consideration, that products, may be forgotten for some time. for example, a computer, and I'm away for a vacation. Those days I didn't use my computer, doesn't have (maybe) an effect of my general usage of this product. So, based on your data, product and intuition you might consider removing gaps like the one I mentioned, and not take it into account inside the calculation.

The amount of time a user has used your product could be a signal of something, but if indeed he only started some time ago, and still using it until today, it may be something you need to take into consideration, and for that use, this average binning technique may help.